# Output in two-part Fractional Response Model (FRM) package incorrect?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model, quasi-likelihood

I was experimenting with the Fractional Response Model (FRM) package, and decided to replicate the results using the base GLM package to better understand the theory. I am able to replicate the results, however, I would have expected the `frm$yhat2P` output to be different.

Consider the case where we are estimating a two-part fractional regression model with y = 1 as the relevant boundary value, using a probit binary link function and a logit fractional link function. I have generated some toy data to work with below. We create this function using the `frm` package as such:

```r
set.seed(1337)
N <- 250
u <- rnorm(N)
X <- cbind(rnorm(N), rnorm(N))
dimnames(X)[[2]] <- c("X1", "X2")
ym <- exp(X[, 1]+X[, 2]+u)/(1+exp(X[, 1]+X[, 2]+u))
y <- rbeta(N, ym*20, 20*(1-ym))
y[y > 0.9] <- 1

temp <- frm(y, X, linkbin="probit", linkfrac="logit", type="2P", 
             inf=1)
df2 <- as.data.frame(round(temp$yhat2P, 8)) 
                 # store results for future reference.
```

The first-part of the `frm` model above can be replicated using `glm` in the following way:

```r
X2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(X,y))
X2$y_binary <- ifelse(y == 1, 1, 0)
temp2 <- glm(y_binary ~ X1+X2, family = binomial("probit"), 
              data = X2) # Generates the likelihood of y = 1. 
summary(temp2) 
    # Produces identical coefficients etc. as the FRM package 
      # first-part.
```

The second-part of the `frm` model above can be replicated using `glm` in the following way:

```r
X3 <- X2[X2$y_binary!=1,]
temp3 <- glm(y~X1+X2, family=quasibinomial("logit"), data = X3) 
   # this generates the fractional response for y[0,1).
summary(temp3) 
    # Produces identical coefficients etc. 
    # as the FRM package second-part.
```

Finally, replicating the `frm` `temp$yhat2P` results (`df2` produced above), i.e., the overall fitted mean values using `glm` can be done as such:

```r
test <- as.data.frame(round(predict(temp2,newdata=X2, 
          type = "response"),8)) # 1st part.
names(test)[1] <- "first_part"
test$second_part <- round(predict(temp3,newdata=X2, 
                    type = "response"),8) # 2nd part.
test$final_part <- round(test$first_part*test$second_part, 8) 
                  # final step.
```

The formula to generate these results is essentially the following (first_part*second_part):

$$
E(y|x) = Pr[y = 1|x]*E[y | x, y[0,1)]
$$

This output, however, is not consistent with how I interpret the frm theory, as found in Ramalho et al's 2011 paper (the author of the package) *"Alternative estimating and testing empirical strategies for fractional regression models"* and other supporting papers. I would expect the output should align with the following formula instead (for this particular case):

$$
E(y|x) = E[y | x, y[0,1)]*Pr[y[0,1) | x] + E[y | x, y = 1]*Pr[y = 1|x]
$$

Which I believe is produced using `glm` as in the following way:

```r
test$what_I_expect <- round(test$second_part*(1-test$first_part) 
                           + (1*test$first_part), 8)
```

Why is the `frm$yhat2P` output not consistent with the formula above? Am I misunderstanding the theory behind two-part FRM models? Or is it possible I am misinterpreting the `frm` package output? Any guidance and/or clarity would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know, and this is a little too much for me to dig into right now, but would digging through the [source code](https://github.com/cran/frm/blob/master/R/frm.R#L567-L568) help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am aware of this bug. Your formula is correct and in fact I have used it in my JPA 2010 paper. However, later on, when constructing the frm package, I implemented the formula for the case where the observed boundary value is 0 and forgot to adapt it to the case you are considering (by the way, I promptly answered your 2 previous emails regarding this question).